# Is it possible to preload glibc?

Tags: dynamic-linking, c++, glibc

One of my client runs a glibc-2.7 based system , and my static linked program wasn't able to start on the target machine, raising an error:

`_ZNSt7num_getlcSt19istreambuf_iteratorIcSt11char_traitsIcEEE2idE, version GLIBCXX_3.4`

So I'm wondering if I can use LD_PRELOAD and passing on the glibc on the develop machine? And if it's possible, what file should be copied there?

Comment: If your executable is failing because of unresolved symbols, it's not statically linked. And as pointed out by Ignacio, that's not a libc symbol, but a C++ symbol (libstdc++). The safest way to handle this is to build against the same version of libraries that your client has. (Or really statically linking.)

Comment: @Mat , yeah i'm going to rebuild a gentoo system with everything static linked , that should solve the issue

Comment: Woah! Don't build a statically-linked distro, that would be mayhem. Just build your code statically (`-static`, `-static-libgcc`, `-static-libstdc++` - potentially huge exes though).

Comment: @Mat , it's a graphic program .. Qt based , that's really kinda hell .. just build Qt may cost 2 hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd probably find it more productive to either preload or static-link libstdc++ instead.